# Floorcasting not scrolling in raycaster?

Tags: java, raycasting

I'm currently working on a raycaster in Java, and so far, I have the floor correctly textured. The problem, however, is that the floor doesn't scroll. In other words, when I move the camera in the projection, the floor stays the same, yet the walls move as expected. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I took almost all the code from [this](https://github.com/vinibiavatti1/RayCastingTutorial/wiki/Floorcasting) reference. Note that I took some liberties when pasting the code in that I used some pseudocode.

I tried applying a player offset to the tileX and tileY variables, e.g., tileX += player.x, and all I got was a floor that scrolls far too quickly and incorrectly.

```
for every ray:
   ... // other stuff relating to the walls above here.
   int start = (int)(wallY + wallHeight + 1);
   double directionCos = cos(rad(ray.getAngle()));
   double directionSin = sin(rad(ray.getAngle()));
   int textureDim = 16;
   for (int y = start; y < screenHeight; y++) {
       double distance = screenHeight / (2.f * y - screenHeight);
       distance /= cos(rad(player.getAngle()) - rad(ray.getAngle()));
       // The source I grabbed the code from actually appends the player's x and y to the tileX and tileY variables, but this completely messes up the textures when I try to.
       double tileX = distance * directionCos;
       double tileY = distance * directionSin;

       int textureX = Math.floorMod((int)(tileX * textureDim), textureDim);
       int textureY = Math.floorMod((int)(tileY * textureDim), textureDim);
       int rgb = floorTexture.getRGB(textureX, textureY);
       projectionFloor.setRGB((int)wallX, y, rgb);
  }
```

Below is an image of the floor.
[image: This is what the floor currently looks like]

Below is an animation visualizing the problem.
[image: Animation of what's wrong]

Below is an animation visualizing what happens if I try to apply a player position offset (it’s not easy to tell, but the scrolling is much faster than it should be and scrolls in the wrong direction most of the time):
[image]